# How does the Dynatrace OneAgent change the dotnet application HTTP header

Tags: c#, dynatrace, apm

I am interesting about dotnet application monitoring. I found that OneAgent which is developed by Dynatrace is great.

I want to know how the agent added the HTTP header to the HTTP request, even though I didn't change anything.

I found the agent added the following headers.

```
X-dynatrace:
X-dynatrace-Application:
X-dynatrace-Origin-URL
X-dynatrace-RequestState:
```

Anyone knows how these headers were added to the http request?

Comment: This is not a technical question or No one is interested in it?

Comment: Since this is proprietary technology I doubt you will get very specific answers, I hope my answer clarifies things a little.

Answer (score 0):

The Dynatrace OneAgent gets automatically injected into .NET applications, and instruments certain functions having to do with the handling of HTTP requests. It is then able to modify HTTP requests while they are handled by the application, to add the headers you observed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am building a monitor platform for our company. I have read some document about DotNet monitor. I know most of them are using  ICorProfilerCallback interface which is provided by microsoft.  But it a callback (before invoke the method & after the method) we can't changed the http header by it. Because it is based on C++ but Application based on C#.